# Pillow on m2 mac

Tags: python-imaging-library

I have the latest Python and Pillow installed on my Mac m2 machine.

I can figure out why Pycharm is throwing this error related to the Pillows architecture mismatch:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.11 /Users/janispipars/Documents/PycharmProjects/_pythonProjects/TEMP_2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/janispipars/Documents/PycharmProjects/_pythonProjects/TEMP_2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 82, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Code:

from PIL import Image

```
def process_image_metadata(filepath: str) -> dict:
    with Image.open(filepath) as img:
        resolution_dpi = img.info.get('resolution')
        horizontal_resolution = img.info.get('dpi')[0]
        vertical_resolution = img.info.get('dpi')[1]
        file_size_mb = img.size[0] * img.size[1] * img.info.get('bits', 8) / 8 / 1024 / 1024

    metadata = {
        'resolution_dpi': resolution_dpi,
        'horizontal_resolution': horizontal_resolution,
        'vertical_resolution': vertical_resolution,
        'file_size_mb': file_size_mb
    }

    return metadata

image_filepath = 'file:///Users/janispipars/Pictures/----%3E%20PHOTO/-   %3E%20PHOTO/_Arhivs/_NK/F120_1_0669P.tif'
metadata = process_image_metadata(image_filepath)
print(metadata)
```

Thank you in advance,
Janis

I did reainstall Python 3.11 and Pillow 10

Comment: Did you try outside of PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

I changed IDE to Visual Studio Code and the code runs smoothly.
No architecture mismatch errors again.

Best,
Janis